# Consolidate Monthly Periods into Annual - SumIfs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have monthly mortgage payments with Payment, Interest portion of payment, and Principal portion of payment.

```
Period Payment   Interest    Principal
1      $900      $660         $240
2      $900      $659         $241
...
360    $900      $1           $889
```

I want to consolidate the interest portion of payment into 30 years.

```
Year                1     2     3     4     5     6     7
Interest Payment    $7900 $7500
```

How would I use a `SUMIFS` to sum the first 12 payments for year 1, the next 12 for year 2, the next 12 for year 3?

I tried to do `SUMIFS(Interest_col,Period_col,">0","<=year*12")`, but the last comparison doesn't seem to register in excel. I'm not sure if it's because it's registering as a string?

Comment: I think you are over thinking / complicating this. You just need to `sum` to 12, highlight those 12, then copy them down to the end of your rows.

Comment: @Mech I edited the question to show the annual table. I want to consolidate them all into a separate annual table, not just get the values 12 rows apart from the monthly schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the math is outside the quotes:

```
=SUMIFS(Interest_col,Period_col,">"&(year-1)*12,Period_col,"<="&year*12)
```

With your table, something like the following:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,">"&(G2-1)*12,$A:$A,"<="&G2*12)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this below your Year 1 column then copy it over:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C"&(12*H1-10)&":C"&(12*H1+1)))
```

Comment: Note that INDIRECT is volatile - better to use INDEX here.

Comment: In what way? I'm open to more info.

Comment: Basically something like `=SUM(INDEX(C:C,row,):INDEX(C:C,row,))`, where you use the year and similar math to what's been already proposed to calculate the corresponding rows.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this formula would help you.

```
=SUM(OFFSET($B2,(COLUMN()-4)*12,0,12))
```

B2 is the first cell in your [interest column]

Column() returns the column number of the cell in which the formula resides. In my example this is column D (=column 4) and 4-4=0, and 0*12=0 too, meaning we start the B2 and sum up 12 values in that column, as indicated by the "12" at the end.

If you copy the formula to column E `COLUMN()-4` equals 1 and 1*12=12, meaning we sum up the 12 values starting from B14. As you copy the formula to the right the summed range changes in this fashion, taking steps of 12.

There may be a problem at the bottom of the list if there aren't another 12 values in the range the above formula specifies. That shouldn't make a difference unless you have totals there which would then be included in the sum.

Comment: OFFSET is volatile - should be avoided here probably.

Comment: "Volatile" means that the formula is evaluated each time the sheet is calculated. If there are a very large number of calculations this may affect the speed with which the sheet responds - depending upon the speed of the processor in the computer. You would have "a very large" number of calculations if you have a very large number of loans. But you might still use an OFFSET or INDIRECT function if you just want to consolidate the numbers for a new database and then replace the formula with values.